# Reference class from app_code folder in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have legacy classes from another c# project that help me create meta tags.

So far I have not been able to figure out how to reference that class which resides in the app_code folder, in a view. I am only able to reference models.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMvcApplication.Models.Seo>
```

There has to be a way to reference a class from the app_code folder inside the view.

Comment: What did you try? What error do you get?

Comment: I did not get any errors. I am just not able to reference the class. There seems to be no examples on how to use app_code classes directly in the view. I am thinking now that I should only use them inside the controller. Which does not make too much sense, since controllers are classes themselves....

Answer (score 0):

You still need to provide it a means of finding the class via the "using" statement, just like when it is in code:

```
@using YourApp.YourClass;
```

Comment: I tried using @using YourApp.YourClass; But the intellisense pops up YourApp.app_code and then after app_code nothing....

Comment: The using is simply the namespace, not the class name.  This isn't Java.  Once you have the namespace you can use the class.  Of course, you need to use the correct namespace from your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed your namespace in all views automatically, trough in web.config inside the folder views, just put the namespace of the class.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    //existing default namespaces//
    <add namespace="YourNamespaceToSeoUtil"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```